# Stream a video from another server to the client through my nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, npm, video-streaming, nodejs-stream

I have videos stored on a server (server1) that some clients have no access to, and I have another server (server2) that has access to server1 and the clients have access to.

I want those clients to be able to watch those videos through server2 on their browsers.

- I can't just redirect them to server1 cuz they can't access it.
- I can't download and save the videos on server2 cuz I don't have that much of space on it.
- I know how  to stream a **local** video to a client using chunks.
- I know how to download and save a video using http.

Is there any way I can stream those videos from server1 to the clients using nodejs on server2?

Answer (score 0):

The [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#streaming) module is deprecated but they have a nice streaming example

```
const request = require('request');

http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
  if (req.url === '/doodle.png') {
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
      request.get('http://example.com/doodle.png').pipe(resp)
    }
  }
})
```

You can use the request module, it's still rock, or to adapt to any other request alternative or the built in http module.

Comment: I used request module for that and it didn't help me alot because the size of each video is kind of large (around 2 GB) so request module didn't pipe the whole video, it only like the first 10 MB of it. And I also couldn't stream the video in chunks with  request.

Comment: Probably not request issue, probably server issue or proper headers for client. When request \nodejs stream, no one really care about the size.

Comment: BTW, do you have to solve it specifically by NodeJS server? It can easily solved by a well configured proxy

Comment: I used request to pipe a 2 minute video with about 30 mb size and worked just fine. But with 1hr video with 1gb size it gave me just the first 3 minutes of it. I think  the problem in in the size of the response that request can get and pipe.

Comment: is there an article or something you can provide me about the proxy thing?

Comment: It's usually referred as 'reverse proxy', I need more info on the infrastructure to suggest specific solution.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/

Comment: OK, so I got the concept of the proxy server. But how do I fix my problem using nodejs.

Comment: I don't know what cause the request to stop so I can't help you. Try with different file servers to eliminate server issues.